# toDateString() not working to convert a unix timestamp to human-readable format?

Tags: javascript, time, epoch

I'm doing this:

```
console.log('before:' + back[i].dateCreated);
back[i].dateCreated = new Date(back[i].dateCreated).toDateString();
console.log('after: ' + back[i].dateCreated);
```

And I get console logs like this:

```
before:1397091642
after: Fri Jan 16 1970
```

But if I plug that epoc date into [this conveter](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm) it comes out 4/10/2014

So does "toDateString()" not do what I think it does, or is something wrong with my timestamp or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript time is not in seconds but milliseconds. So you have to multiply by 1000:

```
var epoc = 1397091642;
var date = new Date(epoc * 1000);
var humanReadable = date.toDateString();
```